# Record Not Found Error in Rails Webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am attempting to learn how to make a simple Ruby on Rails application. I am creating a field where the user can input data. On submit (or create), this data is saved and then the user returns to the home page. So I have localhost:3000/listings/new to create the model, and then I attempt to get to localhost:3000/listings/1 to view the newly-created model and am met with a Record Not Found error. I'm not sure why this may be, and I have looked for a few hours with no results.

listings_controller.rb

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @listing = Listing.new #calls on new method in listing model
  end

  def create
     @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
     @listing.save
     redirect_to root_path
  end

  def show
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :description, :city, :state, :zipcode)
  end

end
```

new.html.erb and show.html.erb (if needed)

```
<div class="topbar">

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="contact-area">

    <%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
    <!-- taken from schema.rb -->
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %> <!-- use text field when body is just 1 line -->

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %> <!-- more for paragraphs -->

    <%= f.label :city %>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>

    <%= f.label :state %>
    <%= f.text_field :state %>

    <%= f.label :zipcode %>
    <%= f.text_field :zipcode, class: "zip-width", maxlength: "5" %>

    <%= f.submit class: "create-button"%>

    <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
```

AND

```
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="vertical-center">
      <%= link_to 'home', root_path %> > jobs > accounting
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
     <button type="button">reply</button>
     posted <%= time_ago_in_words(@listing.created_at) %>
    <h1 class="listing-header"><%= @listing.title %></h1>
    <div class="box">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <p><%= @listing.description%></p>
   </div>
  <footer>
    <p>post id: <%= @listing.id%></p>
    <p>posted <%= time_ago_in_words(@listing.created_at) %></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  #NOTE USE rake routes TO SEE ALL ROUTES

  #Creates the CRUD actions for categories
  resources :categories do
  resources :subcategories #Creates CRUD actions for subcategories
  end

  resources :listings

  root 'categories#index' #first page that we land on -- homepage

  #matching paths to pages controller
  match '/help', to: 'pages#help', via: :get
  match '/scams', to: 'pages#scams', via: :get
  match '/safety', to: 'pages#safety', via: :get
  match '/terms', to: 'pages#terms', via: :get
  match '/privacy', to: 'pages#privacy', via: :get
  match '/about', to: 'pages#about', via: :get
  match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact', via: :get
end
```

Comment: whats your `root_path`?

Comment: check on rails console if record exists with`id = 1`  or `Listing.find(1)` ?

Comment: I changed it to this and received a URLGenerationError - `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"listings", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id].` Why is my id getting nil right after I click submit? Is there any other code I need to add so you can help me figure this out

Comment: after submitting new form you listing is not created , thats why id is `nil` here

Comment: Right, is there any way to see why (from the code given) this would be the case? I am following an online tutorial pretty closely and it does not seem I've missed anything, so I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: did you create `show.html.erb` ? and check the modified answer

Comment: can you share the `config/routes.rb` file's contents.

Comment: share your `routes.rb` or just run command `rake routes | grep listings` on console and paste your routes for listings.

Comment: @Anand show.html.erb is the last segment of code I posted.

Comment: its alright, now you try the modified answer below and check what's the error on creating listings.

Comment: Please go into the rails console by typing `rails c` in the terminal in the application root directory, then type `Listing.pluck :id` and post the output.

Comment: @CarterKlein can u post screenshot of error?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that when you try to create the listing, you're hitting some type of validation error and the creation is being rolled back. In order to see an informative error about this, update your create action by replacing:

```
@listing.save
```

with

```
@listing.save!
```

The former (what you have) fails silently and just returns false for an invalid record. The latter (with the bang) fails with an exception on an invalid record.

Answer (score -1):

Do it as

```
  def create
     @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
     if @listing.save
       flash[:notice] = "Listing created successfully."
       redirect_to listing_path(@listing)
     else
       flash[:error] = @listing.errors.full_messages
       render 'new'
     end
  end
```

and check the error message in flash